# index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4 Code with Double Sum

Tags: python, bounds, out

Hi I have the following function which produces an out of bounds error:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import scipy
import math
import sympy as sy


T = sy.Symbol('T')
rho = sy.Symbol('rho')


g_T   = [1,T,T**2,T*sy.log(T),T**2*sy.log(T)]
g_rho  = [1,rho,rho**2,rho*sy.log(rho),rho**2*sy.log(rho)]

g_T_np = np.asarray(g_T)
g_rho_np = np.asarray(g_rho)


c = np.loadtxt("c_test.txt")


def F(T,rho):
    ret = 0
    for n in xrange(1,5):
        for m in xrange(1,6):
            inner= c[n,m]*g_T_np*g_rho_np
        ret += inner
    return ret

print F(T,rho)
```

where the .txt file is like this:

```
-0.529586   -0.000208559    -3.36563E-09    2.29441E-05 
2.22722E-06 -0.00014526 -2.48888E-09    1.89488E-05 
-6.26662E-05    0.000421028 6.17407E-09 -5.14488E-05    
0.09977346  -0.000622051    -8.56485E-09    7.49956E-05 
-0.01437627 -9.86754E-05    -1.59808E-09    1.22574E-05
```

The full error displayed is:

`Traceback (most recent call last):File "EOS_test.py", line 38, in <module> print F(T,rho) File "EOS_test.py", line 31, in F inner=c[n,m]*g_T_np*g_rho_np IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4`

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Hi Shaun, welcome to Stack Overflow.  I fixed your formatting.  For future reference, code (and things you want to look like code) is formatted simply by indenting (at least) 4 spaces.  You can also select the code and click the button in the editor that looks like `{}`.

Comment: Can you post the exact error, and indicate which line it occurs in?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: thank you very much for formatting looks a lot better! And thanks for the info how to do it in future.
          The error looks like this \    Traceback (most recent call last):File "EOS_test.py", line 38, in <module>
    print F(T,rho)
  File "EOS_test.py", line 31, in F
    inner= c[n,m]*g_T_np*g_rho_np
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: still looks awful ... does this work within the comments as well? :) sry

Comment: Comments have limited formatting capabilities.  (Click on help by the comment box to see what.)  Your best bet, especially for information relevant to the question, is to edit the question with the extra information.  Please do that, even though I've answered already. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numpy uses 0-based indexing. From the looks of it you are indexing the array from 1 (2nd position) to 4 (5th position), which is of course out of bounds for the array you are working with. The same is true for the second axis.

Secondly, you've mixed up your axes:

- The first axis (0) is the index of the selected row (0 to 5)
- the second axis indexes the column, i.e. the value inside a row (indexed 0 to 4)

This should work:

```
def F(T,rho):
    ret = 0
    for n in range(5):
        for m in range(4):
            inner= c[n,m]*g_T_np*g_rho_np
        ret += inner
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in setting your `xrange`s.

Python lists (and np arrays) are 0 indexed, so you don't want the indices [1,2,3,4,5] and [1,2,3,4,5,6], but instead want <s>[0,1,2,3,4] and [0,1,2,3,4,5]</s> [0,1,2,3] and [0,1,2,3,4].

Setting up your for loops like this would solve your problem:

```
for n in xrange(0,4):
    for m in xrange(0,5):
```

Or, you can take advantage of xrange's default starting point, and simply list one parameter:

```
for n in xrange(4):
    for m in xrange(5):
```

Also, for a "more pythonic" solution, instead of having nested for loops, look up how to iterate over an ndarray.  The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html) give this example:

```
it = np.nditer(c, flags=['f_index'])
while not it.finished:
    inner= c[it[0]]*g_T_np*g_rho_np
    ret += inner
    it.iternext()
```

This avoids the whole issue of needing to know the size of the array you're importing, and is therefore much more robust.

**Edit**: As pdowling mentioned in his answer, the range numbers should be 4 and 5.  I had left 5 and 6 in my aswer, and have now changed that.

Comment: `for n in xrange(0,4): for m in xrange(0,5):`
tried that before didn't work out. Neither did the other options. I think @pdowling was right because when i switched the axis it worked. But thanks for your quick response

Comment: If you found his information helpful, you should upvote it.  (You can upvote or downvote any answer.)  And if it solved your problem, you should click on the checkmark.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: slowly getting the hang out of it! :) thank you very much for your patience.